# Using Lodash _.throttle() with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to use the Lodash throttle function to throttle the onChangeText event on a text input. It doesn't seem to make any difference though:

```
<TextInput {...this.c('tokenInput')}
    onChangeText={ _.throttle((text) => {
        this.onChangeText(text)
    }, 1000) }
    value={this.state.text}
    placeholder='Select...'
/>
```

How can I make this work? Every time I type something into the input it keeps executing onChangeText() with every change.

Comment: That's because you're setting onChangeText equal to the function return value, not the function. That means every time it re-renders it's executing the throttle function. Should be like `onChangeText={ (text) => {/*do throttle stuff here*/} }`

Comment: @Jayce444 I changed it to `onChangeText={(text) => { _.throttle((text) => {
                        this.onChangeText(text)
                    }, 1000) }}`. Now the onChangeText method isn't executed at all. Could you give me an example of how the implementation should look like?

Comment: @Jayce444 `_.throttle` **returns a function**

Comment: have you done the onChangeText function binding anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Dez No, no binding

Answer (score -2, accepted):

onChange must be a function, but in your context it's a function call. So to solve the issue you have to do something like this:

```
<TextInput {...this.c('tokenInput')}
    onChangeText={ text => _.throttle(x => {
        this.onChangeText(x)
    }, 1000)(text) }
    value={this.state.text}
    placeholder='Select...'
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. The onChangeText() method isn't even being executed at all.

Comment: `_.throttle` **returns a function**

Comment: Then onChangeText is the wrong method. Maybe it's just onChange?

Comment: @Tobias onChangeText has been working for so long, that's not the point. The point is I tried using the throttle method in, and that one doesn't work.

Comment: It's because of Li357's comment. I'll make an update

Comment: @Tobias The edited code doesn't make a difference. The method is executed now, but keeps being executed with every keypress in the input. So, still no throttling.

Comment: are you sure it's not throttling? Maybe it just seems not to throttle. Can you change the period to 10000 just to check if it's still not working correctly?

Comment: @Tobias Yeah I thought the same thing and tried it with 10000 :) It really seems not to work though.

Comment: @Tobias Something For the future if you ever run into this issue (and others), it didn't work because the component is re-rendered every time `onChangeText` is fired, so the throttle goes back to zero because it all gets re-rendered. The throttle should be performed inside the function that onChangeText calls and not within the render method itself. Thanks for the help :)